# A, B, C are in order of

Tags: adverbs

Assuming that there are three PCs: PC1, PC2, and PC3. PC1 is most expensive, and PC3 is cheapest.  In this case, does the following sentence make sense?

> I have three PCs: PC1, PC2, and PC3 that are (mentioned) in order of decreasing
>   price.

More specifically, I would like to know whether it is possible to omit the verb "mentioned" or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit "that are mentioned":

> I have three PCs: PC1, PC2 and PC3, in order of decreasing price.

The list is apposition to the noun phrase "three PCs", The last phrase is simply descriptive it doesn't have to be a full clause.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that *mentioned* is incorrect. However, a better choice might be *listed*.

I might say it like this:

> I have three PCs: PC1, PC2, and PC3; they are listed in order of decreasing price.

You could also use *named* instead of *mentioned*.